# Mechanism for the Formation of DMC

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I have recently reviewed the synthesis of the dehydrating agent DMC (7), but I could find no reported mechanisms for its formation. I have proposed the mechanism drawn below, but I am unsure about a few steps.

[image: DMC Mech.]

To start, It is clear that this reaction is similar to the Vilsmier-Haack reaction, as the product is identical to what would be obtained under Vilsmier-Haack conditions; however, it is obvious that a different mechanism must be followed (the lone pair of the imidazolidinone (1) will not be attacking anything after all). I proposed that traces of HCl in the reaction will result in the formation of intermediate 2. The enol form of this can then attack the phthaloyl chloride (3) as expected to form intermediate 4. Of course, this will collapse to form intermediate 5. With no better nucleophiles in the reaction, the expelled chloride will attack intermediate 5. Nitrogen's lone pair could then kick out a carboxylate as a leaving group (I am not very confident about this step). This would form the desired DMC (7).

Now, I would ask why it was necessary to use phthaloyl chloride as opposed to a simple monoacid chloride. I propose this is because the phthaloyl chloride quickly destroys the nucleophilic carboxylate, which might otherwise react with the DMC to form unwanted byproducts. The resulting phthalic anhydride is not nucleophilic, and in the absence of any traces of water, it will not react with the DMC.

[image]

Now, I have 2 questions.

1. Does my mechanism for the formation seem correct? Only traces of HCl will be present in the reaction, so I am not sure if the concentration of the enol form will be enough to react at a reasonable rate. Also, the loss of carboxylate as a leaving group is a little bit worrisome, as always.
2. Because this reaction is so similar to the Vilsmier-Haack reaction, would Vilsmier-Haack conditions be a viable way to form the DMC?

Comment: Nice job, Eli! You really don't need HCl to effect enolization. 1 and 3 will do the acylation on oxygen. Basically a V-H reaction

Comment: @user55119 So, essentially, it could just be one concerted step from intermediate 1 to 4 (i.e. the phthaloyl chloride acts as a proton in a sense). As you said, in this case, no protonation or prior enolization would be required.

Comment: Exactly! Of course, phthaloyl chloride probably contains a trace of HCl.

Comment: I would say that the enolization is not only unnecessary, but the way it's written here it would impede the reaction. See the formation of the Vilsmeier reagent on Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilsmeier_reagent). The amide is nucleophilic because it's neutral and somewhat electron-rich. I might be wrong, but IMO postulating that a protonated, positively charged species attacks a neutral molecule as a nucleophile is a bit counterintuitive.